# seperate elements from array that has certain word

Tags: javascript, node.js

but its only writing on one file and the other one is empty

```
const fs = require("fs")

fs.readFile('storage/shared/file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
let data1 = []
let data2 = []
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
if(data[i].includes("{ND}")) {
data1.push(data[i]) }
else {
data2.push(data[i]) }}
data1 = data1.join("").toString()
data2 = data2.join("").toString()
fs.writeFile('storage/shared/nodata.txt', data1, function(err, data) { if(err) console.log(err) })
fs.writeFile('storage/shared/data.txt', data2, function(err, data) { if(err) console.log(err) }) })
```

Comment: `data` is a string, you're iterating the characters, so it'll never include `"{ND}"`

Answer (score 0):

Since based on your logic you want to write data to nodata.txt only if it contains "{ND}", you don't need to iterate over it because readFile will return a string, so you can just check if that string includes "{ND}" and then write to nodata.txt or data.txt by providing correct path.

```
const fs = require("fs")

fs.readFile('storage/shared/file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    const filePath = data.includes("{ND}") ? 'storage/shared/nodata.txt' : 'storage/shared/data.txt';
    
    fs.writeFile(filePath, data, function(err, data) { 
       if(err) console.log(err) 
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here I am explaining the problem in details - https://youtu.be/_hVCNGNMgpE   Please upvote if answer helped. Thank you.